# Installing pip for Blender and GDAL

Tags: python

I'm trying to configure gdal within blender using the information here: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki/How-to-install-GDAL. I already have blender totally configured and the correct gdal .whl file downloaded but, when I try to install pip (python.exe -m ensurepip) using the command window, I get the following error.

[image]

I check that \2.79\python\Lib\site-packages\easy_install.py' but there isn't that "easy_install.py" file there.
I tried to reinstall blender but still the same result.

Any idea to configure gdal for blender solving or jumping this step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use *Command Prompt as an administrator*  to `ensurepip`?

[image: CMD admin]

You may need to change your directory by `cd "the/folder/blender/python"`

It seems like the system block out the process during I/O writing to the Blender installed folder.

And be careful, Blender uses its own Python in the installed folder as the default executable Python. You may want to bind that python for installing thing through `pip install`.

Comment: As easy as that. Thanks. I'm always trying to get rid of commands but...not this time.